# looping through JSON object checking key values

Tags: jquery

Trying to run the following code

```
var superGroup = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(superGroup, function(idx, obj) {
            if (idx.contains("Addr_Line")) {
                if (obj != null) {
                    currentAddress.push(obj);
                }
            }
        });
```

Where supergroup is a JSON object with a bunch of properties and I basically only want to add the values of the properties in this object which contain "addr_line". In chrome I noticed there is a JS error on

```
idx.contains()
```

Saying idx does not contain a method contains

Any idea how I can get around this ?

Comment: In this case, `idx` will either be a string or a number.  Neither of which have a `.contains()` method.  **EDIT**: [`String.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains) exists, but nothing (except Firefox) supports it.

Comment: When I did a alert(idx), it showed all the property names of my object i.e id,blah,Address_Line_1,Address_Line_2, etc the code seemed to work in firefox but chrome didnt like it

Comment: You could have easily answered this question yourself by [reading the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains#Browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [the docs for `String.contains`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains#Polyfill), you can polyfill this Firefox-only method by adding the following code:

```
if (!('contains' in String.prototype)) {
  String.prototype.contains = function(str, startIndex) {
    return -1 !== String.prototype.indexOf.call(this, str, startIndex);
  };
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is because String.prototype.contains() is not supported in Chrome: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/contains

Just do this:

```
$.each(superGroup, function(idx, obj) {
    if (idx.indexOf('Addr_Line') !== -1) {
        if (obj != null) {
            currentAddress.push(obj);
        }
    }
});
```

You might also want to check if `idx` is a `string`:

```
$.each(superGroup, function(idx, obj) {
    if (typeof idx == 'string' && idx.indexOf('Addr_Line') !== -1) {
        if (obj != null) {
            currentAddress.push(obj);
        }
    }
});
```